# How do I convert a list to a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-3.x

I have a list like this:

```
listedd = ['AAA', 'K', 'AAC', 'N', 'AAG', 'K',]
```

and I want to convert it to a dictionary like this:

```
{'AAA':'K', 'AAC': 'N', 'AAG':'K'}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
>>> l = ['AAA', 'K', 'AAC', 'N', 'AAG', 'K']
>>>
>>> v = iter(l)
>>> {s: next(v) for s in v}
{'AAG': 'K', 'AAA': 'K', 'AAC': 'N'}
```

---

Here's a small time comparison in Python 3.3.2:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> setup = "l = ['AAA', 'K', 'AAC', 'N', 'AAG', 'K']"
>>> 
>>> timeit("v = iter(l); {s: next(v) for s in v}", setup)
0.7127587589984614
>>> 
>>> timeit("dict(zip(l[::2],l[1::2]))", setup)
1.4540460520001943
>>> 
>>> timeit("dict(zip(*[iter(l)]*2))", setup)
1.395266197001547
>>> 
>>> timeit("{k: l[i+1] for i,k in enumerate(l) if not i%2}", setup)
1.4753028479990462
```

---

**Reference:**

- [Dict Comprehensions (PEP 274)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)
- [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)
- [`next()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)

Comment: ... or `dict((s, next(v)) for s in v)` for older versions.

Answer (score 4):

Step through the list by twos, zip the results together, giving a list of tuples that will be your key/value pairs and then convert that list of tuples into a dictionary:

```
>>> dict(zip(l[::2],l[1::2]))
{'AAG': 'K', 'AAA': 'K', 'AAC': 'N'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some flavor:

```
d = { k : listedd[i+1] for i, k in enumerate(listedd) if not i % 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest way is to use slices:

```
>>> listedd = ['AAA', 'K', 'AAC', 'N', 'AAG', 'K',]
>>> result = dict(zip(listedd[::2], listedd[1::2]))
{'AAA': 'K', 'AAC': 'N', 'AAG': 'K'}
```

This code really maps all even elements of list to it's odd elements.

Update: I've missed previous post, sorry))

Answer (score 0):

Another way to use `iter` and `zip`:

```
dict(zip(*[iter(listedd)]*2))
```

Or, if you prefer longer programs to shorter ones:

```
>>> listedd = ['AAA', 'K', 'AAC', 'N', 'AAG', 'K',]
>>> it = iter(listedd)
>>> z = zip(it,it)
>>> d = dict(z)
>>> print d
{'AAG': 'K', 'AAA': 'K', 'AAC': 'N'}
```